# WebSocket.textHandlerID is null after upgrading to Vert.X 4.4

Tags: vert.x

After upgrading from `4.3.2` to Vert.X `4.4.1`, `webSocket.textHandlerID()` is now `null`.

The [release notes](https://github.com/vert-x3/wiki/wiki/4.4.0-Deprecations-and-breaking-changes#disable-writehandler-registration-for-net-sockets-and-websockets-by-default) tell that we can switch back to the previous behavior via `WebSocketConnectOptions` but this only seems to be possible when using a Vert.X HTTP client, or am I missing something here?

How can I switch back to the previous behavior which allowed me to use `webSocket.textHandlerID()` when using a non-Vert.X client (e.g. React JS client) connecting to the Vert.X HTTP endpoint?

**Context**

I'm using `httpServerRequest.toWebsocket()` to upgrade an HTTP connection to a WebSocket connection on the server-side and then use the WebSocket opened by Vert.X to stream messages to my React JS client.

To do so, I'm using `webSocket.textHandlerID()` in `Handler<RoutingContext>.handle(context)` to get the Websocket address of the opened socket.

**Expected**

I expected `webSocket.textHandlerID()` to not change, or find a Vert.X option on the server-side to switch back to the pre-4.4 behavior.

Comment: got bit by this too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this problem with the example below:

```
vertx.createHttpServer(new HttpServerOptions()
      .setRegisterWebSocketWriteHandlers(true))
      .webSocketHandler(new WebSocketHandler())
      .listen(PORT, http -> {
          if (http.succeeded()) {
            startPromise.complete();
            LOG.info("HTTP server started on port {}", PORT);
          } else {
            startPromise.fail(http.cause());
       }});
```

The reason is explained in the doc:

> By default, no handler is registered, the feature must be enabled via {@link WebSocketConnectOptions#setRegisterWriteHandlers(boolean)} or {@link HttpServerOptions#setRegisterWebSocketWriteHandlers(boolean)}

Comment: More info about this in https://github.com/vert-x3/wiki/wiki/4.4.0-Deprecations-and-breaking-changes#disable-writehandler-registration-for-net-sockets-and-websockets-by-default

Comment: `setRegisterWebSocketWriteHandlers(true)` seems to fix it, thanks. I've no idea why I didn't find this myselve.